# Creating new mappings in Vim

Tags: vim

I am trying to create a mapping the allows me to execute my current node.js file when I press comma + n. I am trying to use the following:

```
:map <cn> :!node .
```

When I type this in it simply jumps my cursor to a random line in my current file. How do I create this mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've specified the mapping keys in the wrong format, see `:help key-notation`. To trigger the mapping via <kbd>,</kbd> followed by <kbd>N</kbd>, use this:

```
:nnoremap ,n :!node %<CR>
```

Additional notes:

- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- Likewise, you should be as specific in the modes, so `:nmap` instead of `:map` for *normal mode* only.
- A mapping works as typed. As you invoke an Ex command from normal mode, you need to conclude command-line mode via `<CR>`, just as you would press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when typing this interactively.
- You probably want to pass the current file to `node`; that's done by the special `%` identifier, not by `.`. See `:help cmdline-special`

Comment: Thanks. It seems as though this mapping does not work globally in all files, or once I exit the current file. How do I save the mapping?

Comment: To persist it, you have to put the line into your `~/.vimrc` (or `_vimrc` on Windows) configuration, and restart Vim.

Comment: When I try to use the mapping it states, "E486: Pattern not found: all_gal". I am assuming a mapping I already have is already in the place of those keys. How do I replace it?

Comment: No, it looks like Vim executes the built-in `n` command and that causes the error. Check with `:verbose nmap ,n` that it got defined.